# Generate a interval based time series using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark sql. I want to generate the following series of start time and end time which have an interval of 5 seconds for current date. So in lets say I am running my job on 1st Jan 2018 I want a series of start time and end time which have a difference of 5 seconds. So there will be 17280 records for 1 day

```
START TIME          | END TIME
----------------------------------------- 
01-01-2018 00:00:00 | 01-01-2018 00:00:04
01-01-2018 00:00:05 | 01-01-2018 00:00:09
01-01-2018 00:00:10 | 01-01-2018 00:00:14
.
.
01-01-2018 23:59:55 | 01-01-2018 23:59:59
01-02-2018 00:00:00 | 01-01-2018 00:00:05
```

I know I can generate this data-frame using a scala for loop. My constraint is that I can use only queries to do this.

Is there any way I can create this data structure using select * constructs?

Comment: can you elaborate your phrase `5 second interval time series every day`?

Comment: I want to divide the whole day into 5 second intervals - 01-01-2018 00:00:00 to 01-01-2018 00:00:04 and so till 01-01-2018 23:00:55 to 01-01-2018 23:59:59